# One particle infinite manifestation universe

Tags: electrons, universe, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

I know how non-intuitive everything related to quantum physics is and I was thinking on some very unintuitive things like

1. John Wheeler one electron universe theory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe
2. The fact that it's impossible to "see" past the atom's electron cloud.

   What if the effects that we think are the results of the atom nucleus are in fact the effects of the electron cloud, and the atom nucleus and all other particles that we think exists (based only on their measurable effects) are in fact just effects/manifestation of the electron cloud.

   And because of our material world view our mind found it easer to model them as particles.

Basically is it possible that entire universe is the result of one particle infinite manifestation?

My question is, how and from what to start for a mathematically rigorous proof for this theory so that it can be either proved or reduced to absurdity or at least provide a step forward to a scientific check.

Comment: In order to get an answer to your question, you should study quantum field theory. In particular, you will see that a "particle" is a very problematic object. You can instead argue that there are only fields and their excitations. The best description of nature requires a number of fields, so there most probably isn't just "one" particle.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that I do not understand this theory correctly, but it seems to me that it was disproved by experiment. Indeed, it is possible to strip an atom of its electron cloud. If the nucleus was purely an effect of the electron field, nothing would be left once the electrons are removed. This is not the case. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39193/can-i-move-the-atom-nucleus-only) post.

Note that you can never **mathematically** prove (or disprove) that a theory is correct. The best that you can do is write a consistent theory and check that its predictions are consistent with experiment. You can surely construct a mathematically consistent theory based on the idea that there are no nuclei inside atoms, but it will not describe nature.

Comment: While removing the electron cloud of an atom doesn't prove that the nucleus was there *prior* to the removal of the electron cloud, there's no reason to assume otherwise.  Otherwise we might as well claim that the stars don't exist until we look at them.